# How was the four color theorem proved using brute-force search?

Tags: algorithms, proof-techniques

I recently learned some graph theory in Discrete Structures for Computer Science, we learned about the Four Color theorem, I realize there is a mathematical proof for this topic, but how was it initially proved using computation 50 years ago?

Comment: Have you read [the relevant section of the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem#Summary_of_proof_ideas)? (Also, the proof announcement was in June 1976, so less than 44 years ago.)

Comment: The (arguably) simplest version of the proof is due to [Steinberger](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2010-362-12/S0002-9947-2010-05092-5/S0002-9947-2010-05092-5.pdf), following up on the work of [Robertson, Sanders, Seymour and Thomas](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.158.9438&rep=rep1&type=pdf), who in turn follow up on the original proof of Appel and Haken. There is also a formally verifier proof by [Gonthier](https://www.ams.org/notices/200811/tx081101382p.pdf) and his group.

Comment: This seems more appropriate for [math.se].

Comment: @AaronRotenberg I tried reading that, but it's just a summary, I'm still not completely clear on what they did.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus thank you, I'll try to read up on that.